# Does the Continuum hypothesis say anything about the cardinality of the set $3^{{\aleph}_0}$?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

I thought of this amazing method which produces a set of cardinality $3^n$ from a set of cardinality $n$:

If we take a set S of cardinality $n$ and produce ordered pairs of the form (A,B), where A and B are subsets of S such that $A\cap B =\emptyset$, then the set of all those ordered pairs has cardinality $3^n$. This is simply the multinomial theorem. I even tested this on the set {1,2}. I got $3^2=9$ ordered pairs: ($\emptyset$, $\emptyset$), ($\emptyset$, {1}), ($\emptyset$, {2}), ($\emptyset$, {1,2}), ({1}, $\emptyset$), ({2,} $\emptyset$), ({1,2}, $\emptyset$), ({1},{2}), and ({2},{1}).

Let's call this set of cardinality $3^n$, the superpower set of  S. I was wondering that, if we assume the continuum hypothesis to be true, can we derive the cardinality of the superpower set of Natural numbers? What implication does $2^{{\aleph}_0}={{\aleph}_1}$ have on $3^{{\aleph}_0}=?$. Does $3^{{\aleph}_0}$ equal ${{\aleph}_2}$ or something?

Comment: As you can see by the Answer from Hayden, if  $k$ is an infinite cardinal and $A$ is a (finite or infinite cardinal) witjh $2\leq A\leq k$ then $A^k=2^k.$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, given $\kappa$ an infinite cardinal, we have
$$ 2^\kappa \leq 3^\kappa \leq (2^\kappa)^\kappa = 2^{\kappa\cdot\kappa}=2^\kappa$$
showing that $2^\kappa = 3^\kappa$. Thus, if $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_\alpha$, then $3^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_\alpha$.

(*Alternate Solution*) For another (easier) way of thinking of it, we can define an explicit injection of $3^\kappa$ into $2^\kappa$. For simplicity we will just do the case where $\kappa=\aleph_0$, but there isn't too much difficulty extending to arbitrary $\kappa$ (infinite cardinal). The idea is to think of $2^{\aleph_0}$ as being the set of countably-infinite sequences of $0$'s and $1$'s, $2^\mathbb{N}$. Likewise, $3^{\aleph_0}$ is the set of countably-infinite sequences of $0$'s, $1$'s, and $2$'s, $3^\mathbb{N}$. We can 'encode' a sequence in $3^{\aleph_0}$ by using the encoding 
$$0 \mapsto 00, 1 \mapsto 01, 2 \mapsto 11$$ 
In other words, we define $f: 3^{\mathbb{N}} \to 2^{\mathbb{N}}$ by sending a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \in 3^\mathbb{N}$ to the sequence $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ where
$$y_{2n},y_{2n+1} = \begin{cases} 0,0 & \text{if $x_n = 0$} \\ 0,1 & \text{if $x_n=1$} \\ 1,1 & \text{if $x_n=2$} \end{cases}$$
$f$ is an injection, and there is another obvious injection $2^\mathbb{N} \to 3^\mathbb{N}$. Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein then shows $2^{\aleph_0} = 3^{\aleph_0}$.

(*Alternate Solution 2*) For a fun proof, note that when you put the discrete topology $3=\{0,1,2\}$, $3^\mathbb{N}$ (with the product topology) is a compact metrizable topological space. But since compact metrizable spaces are second-countable, the cardinality of $3^\mathbb{N}$ is at most continuum, i.e. $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: Why does ($(2^k)^k$) equal $2^k$?

Comment: @RyderRude For infinite cardinals, $\kappa \cdot \kappa=\kappa$. Admittedly this is a bit of a sledgehammer of a result, but in the case where $\kappa = \aleph_0$ this is a standard fact.

Comment: I was wondering, what if we drop the condition $A\cap B=\emptyset$, in my production of ordered pairs? What would be the cardinality of the set of ordered pairs which need not obey that condition?

Comment: In that case, you'd would simply have pairs of subsets, so a set of cardinality $2\cdot 2^{\aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_0}$.